# ACF for custom post type archive pages: which hook to use?

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to register ACF options pages for each custom post type defined in the theme:

```php
$post_types = get_post_types(
    array(
        'public'   => true,
        '_builtin' => false
    ),
    'objects'
);

foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
    $post_type_slug = $post_type->name;
    $options_title = $post_type->labels->name . ": Archive Options";
    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title' => $options_title,
        'menu_title' => $options_title,
        'parent_slug'   => "edit.php?post_type={$post_type_slug}",
        'menu_slug' => "{$post_type_slug}-archive-options",
        'capability' => 'edit_posts',
        'redirect' => false
    ));
}
```

This is called on the `acf/init` hook (as recommended [by the docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_add_options_page/)), while the custom post types are registered on WordPress `init` hook. (I should also probably mention that both actions are hooked as part of an `after_setup_theme` action.)

However, `get_post_types()` returns an empty array. Is this a sequence mismatch between the hooks? (i.e. posts are registered only after the `acf/init` hook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a sequence mismatch between the hooks?

I would argue so, yes. `acf/init` gets executed by class ACF's `init` method, all in the root file acf.php - this method is hooked to WordPress' `init` with a priority of 5 like so

```
add_action( 'init', array($this, 'init'), 5 );
```

And you probably add your CPTs with a higher priority, this means `acf/init` will be executed before the registering of the custom post types.

To solve this, I would hook into `init` with a even higher priority (smaller than 5) to register the CPTs.

Comment: Thank you, @kero! That was exactly it.